# Type command not working in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have recorded a selenium script.While executing type command in it,it is executing successfully,but typed values are not showing in the respective fields.I  later found out that given input data is  not entering in the application under test too.What is the problem??Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please share HTML code of the elements?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of filling form with `type` command you can try `typeKeys` one. It simulates keystroke events on the specified element, as though you typed the value key-by-key and probably it will help. see [javadoc for TypeKeys](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#typeKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

Type and TypeKeys no longer work as of Firefox 11 or 12 (see link at bottom). I had to use the sendKeys command (comment #12 in link) which has the values appear and simulates keystroke events.

Hope this helps. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3861